# Calculate Tithe from Income

Tags: recursion

Hi I need help calculating the amount I need to donate as tithe (1/10 of income) every year.

Say my annual income before tax is `$50000` and the tax rate is `30%`. Which means my income after tax is `$50000 x 0.7 = $35000`. So I will donate `$3500` as tithe.

Now since donation is tax free in my country, any donation `>= $2` can claim the tax back. Which means I can claim back `30%` of `$3500`, which is `$1050`.

That `$1050` now becomes my income and I should again donate 1/10 of it as tithe, which is `$105`.

The same process repeats again after claiming tax back for that `$105` donation until the donation is `< $2` where it is too little to be claimable.

Without doing the whole process repeatedly over multiple tax claims and donations, I want to know the exact amount I should donate as tithe in one go (obviously will be `> $3500`), so that the tax claimed back is kept for myself.

Please answer with formula of variables rather than exact amount used in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We care about three quantities: the amount of money you make before taxes $(G)$, the amount you offer as tithe $(T$), and the amount you pay in taxes $(X)$.

You don't pay any taxes on the amount you give away as tithe, but you do pay taxes on the rest. Therefore, with a tax rate of 30%, we have in general:
$$X = 0.3\cdot(G-T)$$

You want to give away 10% of your after-tax income as tithe:
$$T = 0.10  (G-X) $$

Let's combine these two equations to eliminate $X$ so that we have:

$$T = 0.10G - 0.10(0.3G-0.3T)$$
$$T = 0.07G + 0.03T$$
$$0.97T = 0.07G$$
$$\boxed{T = \frac{7}{97}G}$$
$$T \approx 0.0721 \cdot G$$

For example, if you make \$50000 before taxes, you would pay around \$3608.24 in tithe—slightly more than the \$3500 you would pay if you didn't use the recursive formula.

---

Note: If I understand your situation correctly, we can ignore the \$2 limit as long as you're giving away the entire tithe $T$ all in one payment and its total value is greater than \$2. For example, if you just give your entire tithe of \$3608.24 all at once, it's not taxable.

---

And in the general problem where tithes are untaxed and you want to recursively pay $p$ percent of your income as tithe given $q$ percent tax rate, the same algebraic reasoning shows you should pay

$$T = \frac{p(1-q)}{1-pq}G$$
which agrees with our earlier answer.

Comment: Wow impressive! All points in the question checked with detailed explanation, definitely the kind of answer I am looking for and I've learnt a lot from you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to find:
$$3500+105+3.15+\cdots=\frac{3500}{1-0.3\cdot 0.1}=\frac{3500}{0.97}\approx 3608.247.$$
Note: $T_{n+1}=0.03T_n, T_1=3500$.

Comment: Thank you, you are quick but I found yours a bit hard to understand where the numbers come from (my bad), so I picked the other.

Comment: I am with you, the one you picked is comprehensive. To help with the numbers: $3500+3500\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.1+3500\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.1\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.1+\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$=gross income and $T$=tithe.

Your after-tax income, for purposes of computing the tithe is $$.7G+.3T,$$ and the tithe is $10$ percent of this:
$$T=.07G+.03T\implies .97T=.07G\implies\\
\boxed{T=\frac{7}{97}G\approx .0722G}$$

This gives $T=\$3608.25\text{ when } G=\$50000.$

Comment: Very clever way to see through the issue, and you were very quick to answer too. Deserve more upvotes!